# What online tools in 2023 are effective at vectorizing shaded AI renders without generating many color gradients?

Tags: vector

I have modified an excellent render of several automobiles done in a retro style, making them more accurate to the vehicle, but the graphic uses many gradients that could be done with either radial or linear vectors. The reference image below has several gradients made on [vectorizer.io](https://www.vectorizer.io). Limitations in AI don't allow mixing classic and modern vehicles in one render so I had to manipulate them myself. Now I need the final as a vector.

Currently there are MANY online vector conversion programs being advertised, as AI has become cheap and prolific. But which one handles mapping bitmap gradients to vector gradients best? Anything that can output more than the basic linear and radial gradients would be preferred. I don’t know what engine vectorizer uses but is there an engine I should look for in this?

Example:
[image: Gradients in a bitmap]

Comment: Auto tracing won't create proper gradients.  Better to simplify your image in a raster image editor by removing the larger gradients, then trace in Illustrator/Inkscape etc, then add the gradients back in manually. [see a rough example](https://imgur.com/a/0i1Uid9)

Comment: So the problem is that there is no good reliable vector standard for arbitrary gradients. The systems in place just aren't good enough. So even if you could make vector gradients in the way you like, it would most likely not work on the application users end reliably.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware **no** auto-tracer will render gradients for output.

They **all** read gradients as "steps" of color, and then render those (banded) *steps* as separate objects, not one object with a gradient fill.

I have *never* seen a gradient output from *any* tracing tool.

Comment: I have been using [vectorizer.io](https://www.vectorizer.io/) for a while and generated the gradients for the reference image with it, but it only allows radial and linear gradient output.

Comment: Using that service - A very simple, rudimentary test  containing just *one* simple multi-colored linear gradient showed [*zero rendered gradients*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcSoE.png) It failed to create either a linear or radial gradient.

Comment: I was able to render the blue fender and grey Vette fender eliminating many polygons. Maybe the service changed. AI is so fluid today.